# Protect routes in Laravel with angular

Tags: angular, laravel, laravel-5

I followed this tutorial https://remotestack.io/laravel-angular-jwt-token-based-authentication-example/ and it is working but issue is i'm able to access routes that should be not accessible without login. There is a route `user-profile` it can be accessed without login but i want it to redirect to login page in case user is not logged in.

> api.php

```
Route::group([
    'middleware' => 'api',
    'prefix' => 'auth'
], function ($router) {
    Route::post('/signup', [JwtAuthController::class, 'register']);
    Route::post('/signin', [JwtAuthController::class, 'login']);
    Route::get('/user', [JwtAuthController::class, 'user']);
    Route::post('/token-refresh', [JwtAuthController::class, 'refresh']);
    Route::post('/signout', [JwtAuthController::class, 'signout']);

    Route::post('/req-password-reset', [ResetPwdReqController::class, 'reqForgotPassword']);
    Route::post('/update-password', [UpdatePwdController::class, 'updatePassword']);
});
```

Any Solution, Thanks

Comment: You can also protect your angular routes with a canActivate guard.

Comment: You must redirect user with angular, not with api - api can just answer 403 forbidden to angular. And if 403 - redirect to login.